# Shopify Embedded App gets same_site_cookies error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app, samesite

Does anyone encountered issue embedding Rails app to Shopify?

I keep getting `oauth_error=same_site_cookies` from Shopify. I tried to install `gem "rails_same_site_cookie"`

also tried to update Rails config for session_store e.g

`Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, {same_site: :none (or :lax),  same_party: true,  secure: true} ...`

but still no success.

[image]
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: No, we move to other option.

Comment: what was the other option @aldrien.h?

Comment: @aldrien.h can you please share how you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

On my case was the lack of "access_scopes" column on the shop model which triggered the error. The best option is to try to insert the shop from the rails console:

```
 Shop.create! {shopify_domain: 'foo...'}
```

Comment: Can you link to documentation that says you need a column named "access_scopes" on the shop model?